# How to share single package or class between Gradle modules?

Tags: java, gradle, module

I have a main project with multiple modules.

I can share module into another module by adding dependency as:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":different-module")
}
```

But can I somehow limit this by package or classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn’t know about packages or classes. So the answer is no.